# Como escrever "edit" em português no contexto de um "post"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Já todos reparamos em posts nos quais o autor escreve **"edit"** a meio do texto para indicar que acrescentou mais conteúdo após uma anterior redacção.

Por exemplo:

```
Um texto escrito num primeiro momento 
(...)

Edit:

Mais texto acrescentado num momento posterior.
(...)
```

A minha pergunta é qual seria a forma mais correcta de escrever o mesmo em português?

Comment: Sendo escrito, você pode compor e revisar a mensagem antes de enviá-la; As it is written, you can compose it and edit it before sending it. https://formandosircespinho.blogs.sapo.pt/906.html

Comment: Adding text can be considered updating and not editing. So, your question is unclear.

Comment: Google's dictionary: 1.
prepare (written material) for publication by correcting, condensing, or **otherwise modifying it**.
"Volume I was edited by J. Johnson"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que eu tenho usado é ***atualização.*** Em geral, *atualização* não equivale ao inglês [*edit* (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/edit_1?q=edit), que pode ser qualquer modificação ou correção de um texto. Mas no contexto é absolutamente correto: trata-se atualizar o post com informação adicional. É até mais preciso que *edit*, que poderia ser simplesmente uma correção da pontuação ou ortografia.

No mesmo sentido poderias usar [***adenda*** (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/adenda). Parece-me que *atualização* dá mais a ideia de que o material acrescentado é importante.

E se não fores muito purista, poderás mesmo considerar ***edição***, mas estarás a esticar o significado aceite do termo. Por exemplo, o Priberam define [*edição*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) como ’ato de editar’, mas define [*editar*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/editar) apenas como ’publicar’ ou ’preparar para publicação’. Isto não cobre o significado que pretendemos aqui. Um dicionário dos mais conceituados, o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) diz a mesma coisa. Mas o Michaelis já nos dá alguma cobertura: define [*edição*](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o/) como ’ato ou efeito de editar’ e [*editar*](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/editar/) como ’alterar, corrigir ou modificar texto ou programa’. Agora, restringe é este significado à informática; mas uma alteração num post não fundamentalmente diferente de uma alteração de um texto num processador de texto.

E é claro, *edição* tem mais uma catrefada de significados que não interessam aqui (mais ou menos equivalente ao inglês *edition*): publicação de um livro, conjunto de cópias de um livro publicadas numa ocasião, montagem de um programa de rádio ou televisão, cada uma das realizações periódicas de um festival ou outro evento, etc. E isto é mais uma razão para preferir o termo mais específico *atualização*.

Comment: atualização é updating, não editing. edit in English means to proofread or correct something. updating a blog post, for example, is not the same as editing a blog post....

Comment: O Bad-coder deixa muito claro que no contexto da pergunta *edit* significa ’adição de informação’;  não significa nem ’proofread’ nem ’correct’. *Actualização* serve perfeitamente neste contexto. E um texto adicional no fim do post, que é o que *edit* designa na pergunta, é, em sentido estrito, uma adenda, como eu sugiro. Pelo contrário, *revisar* ou *rever* não servem neste contexto.

Comment: Jacinto, please. updating is atualização. In English, if you edit, you can change things too. There is no way that the English word edit is atualização. I'm sorry. It just is not that. If he meant updating something, he should have said it. If atualização is what you want, the English needs to be updating and not editing.

Comment: *Edit* tal como usado nesta pergunta **é** uma atualização ou adenda. Tu podes argumentar que nesse contexto deveria ter sido usado *update* e não *edit* (e eu até te dou [alguma razão](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314025/name-for-having-no-concern-about-the-truthfulness-of-one-s-own-remarks)). Mas mudam-se os tempos, mudam-se as vontades, e *edit* é usado aqui neste site e no ELU para designar informação acrescentada no fim do post. Não é culpa minha.

Answer (score 1):

to edit a text or post é revisar um texto ou post.

editor (em este caso) é um revisor, pode ser em alguns casos, um redator.

Neste caso, não darei outras informações porque faz anos que faço esse tipo de trabalho.

edit can also just be: corrigir

Comment: Pois isto deixa-me numa situação difícil para saber qual das respostas devo aceitar. Porque a resposta do Jacinto parece-me a mais correcta em português europeu, enquanto a sua escolha de termos parece-me fazer mais sentido em português brasileiro. Pronto, vou aceitar a outra resposta porque o Jacinto explicou a semantica de cada palavra e conseguiu esgotar os sentidos de cada palavra relacionando-as.

Comment: @bad_coder Faz o que quiser. A resposta pouco tem a ver com PB e PE. Se diz revisar textos em Portugal. Sería exatamente a mesma coisa. E a semântica também não é importante. O Jacinto sugeriu atualização, que é update, não edit.... https://run.unl.pt/bitstream/10362/13518/1/Guia.para.Revisores.de.Texto.pdf